# Woocommerce not saving form field

Tags: woocommerce

i cannot figure out what i am missing.

I created a custom textfield at the woocommerce checkout with a predefined value. Function is pretty standard:

```
function one_more_field(){
    $product_name='';
    global $product;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $productvariation = $cart_item['variation_id'];
    }
woocommerce_form_field( 'variatie', array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'value'       => $productvariation,
        ),
    $productvariation );
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'one_more_field' );
```

I can see the field in the checkout and the variation ID is nicely inserted.

Then step 2: saving the value to the user meta data:

```
function reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta( $customer_id, $posted ) {
        $dob4 = 'test';
        if (isset($posted['variatie'])) {
        $dob4 = $posted['variatie'];
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'variatie', $dob4);
        }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'reigel_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 2 );
```

However, the value is not saved to the user meta data.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you clarify which field(s) you want to create specifically? your code contains some strange steps like the get_cart() action. 
Why should this be added to the user meta data 
versus post meta data?

Comment: You are right, i summarized it but not entirely clear communicatied. The code is shortened to not make a too big story here. I try to store some product information in the user meta because of a synchronisation with another app that works with user meta data. One thing i wanted to store is the product variation name. Woocommerce does not allow (yet?) to add a hidden field to the customers details. Saving the pre-populated field did started to work when i added a 'required' => 'yes' to the field arguments. I dont really understand why it has to be required but it works nevertheless...

Answer (score 0):

Oh it turns out to be very straightforward: just add required => yes to the array of field arguments and it is saved. Cant really understand why though...

So new code (step 1) is:

```
function one_more_field(){
    $product_name='';
    global $product;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $productvariation = $cart_item['variation_id'];
    }
woocommerce_form_field( 'variatie', array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'value'       => $productvariation,
        'required'    => 'true'
        ),
    $productvariation );
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'one_more_field' );
```